# Ruby Source code Auto-Formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pretty-print

What is the best option? I found:

- https://github.com/jasonl/eden
- http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html

but they both seem slightly outdated. Special support for Rails (Knowing which files to format automagically and some other cool things) would be a plus, and a git hook script.

Comment: well - the "best" option is justifiable to speculate on.. but I use my favorite editor, Eclipse.  I have a custom formatter enabled, and i just do Ctrl+Shift+F and voila.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 can "reindent" Ruby code, as can Vim.

Comment: I would love to see something as comprehensive as [perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) in ruby.

Comment: rubocop is currently implementing some of this functionality. It's a style checker, but with optional auto-fixing of style-warnings. It's not nearly far enough to put it here as answer though ;)

Comment: The first link is now dead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop):

```
gem install rubocop
rubocop -a
```

It will also fix all the common mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use vim, in command mode press **gg=G**

1. **gg** - move cursor to the beginning of your file
2. **=** - reindent
3. **G** - till the end of file

Comment: formatting is more than only *indentation*